# /etc/resolv.conf managed by NM?

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, dns, lan, resolv.conf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a DNS server via resolv.conf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf)

I discovered (with great disappointment) that in 12.04 the file `/etc/resolv.conf` no longer contains the real nameserver IP, but just `127.0.0.1`.

In order now to know which is the DNS, we have to "easily" type the simple command

```
nmcli dev list iface eth0
```

My question is this: What if I need to change (and I need it very often in my LAN) the nameserver and the search domain? Can we continue using `/etc/resolv.conf` or is there some new "magic"?