# Internet Good but update manager not good

Tags: 12.04, update-manager, usb-modem

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I am doing Internet with a USB Modem of 236kbps. My issue is that if I am accessing a web page through a browser it works, but if I am doing `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal, there is no response. Please help me to solve this.

One more thing; I am unable to change my DNS settings.

```
raja@badfox:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 220.226.100.40
nameserver 220.226.6.104
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

I want to replace these addresses with ones linked here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/free-dns-server/.

See the picture to have some idea about my issue .[image]

Comment: You can also use [Google Public Free DNS server](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#testing), you can view the **LINUX** section there to configure it.

Comment: @tijybba , thanks for the link but see my post i cant edit & edit will overwrite . so i want to save my changes with out overwritten .

Comment: You can add your choice of DNS below the currently present , see my answer for editing them , so that solves OVERWRITING issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu 12.04 changes were made to DNS resolving, announced [here](http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/); also see the resolvconf [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/resolvconf.8.html).

Changes state that

> resolvconf is a set of script and hooks managing DNS resolution. The
>   most notable difference for the user is that any change manually done
>   to `/etc/resolv.conf` will be **lost** as it gets overwritten next time
>   something triggers resolvconf. Instead, resolvconf uses DHCP client
>   hooks, a Network Manager plugin and `/etc/network/interfaces` to
>   generate a list of nameservers and domain to put in /etc/resolv.conf.

**"I use static IP configuration, where should I put my DNS configuration?"**

> The DNS configuration for a static interface should go as
>   “dns-nameservers”, “dns-search” and “dns-domain” entries added to the
>   interface in /etc/network/interfaces

---

**To try from Older method i.e. prior to Ubuntu 12.04 edition**

> NOTE: Before you change your DNS settings to use Google Public DNS or
>   OpenDNS, be sure to backup the current server addresses or settings
>   somewhere. It is very important that you keep these numbers for backup
>   purposes, in case you need to revert to them at any time.

**Option A: Changing DNS server settings on Ubuntu can be  configured through Network Manager.**

In the **System Settings...**, go to **Network**, then  Select the connection for which you want to configure Google Public DNS.

- To change the settings for an **Ethernet connection**, select the Wired tab, then select your network interface in the list. It is usually called `eth0`.
- To change the settings for a Wireless connection, select the **Wireless** tab, then select the appropriate wireless network.
- Click **Edit**, and in the window that appears, select the IPv4 Settings or IPv6 Settings tab according to your needs.
- If the selected method is Automatic (DHCP), open the dropdown and select `Automatic (DHCP) addresses` only instead. If the method is set to something else, do not change it.
- In the DNS servers field, enter the Google Public DNS IP addresses, separated by a space:

  For IPv4:

  ```
  8.8.8.8 and/or 8.8.4.4
  ```

  For IPv6:

  ```
  2001:4860:4860::8888 and/or 2001:4860:4860::8844
  ```
- Click Apply to save the change. If you are prompted for a password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation. [Test](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#testing) your settings here.

**Option B: Alternately through CLI**

- Edit `/etc/resolv.conf`:

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf
  ```
- If any nameserver lines appear, backup the IP addresses for future reference.
- Replace the nameserver lines with, or **ADD** the following lines:

  For IPv4:

  ```
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
  nameserver 8.8.4.4
  ```

  You can select your [Linked](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/free-dns-server/) addresses here.

  For IPv6:

  ```
  nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
  nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844
  ```
- Save and exit. And again test it from above link.

[*Source*](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using).

Comment: hmm i tried already to change dns with sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf but its saving and overwrite what have typed . for that auto overwrite the reason also displayed . your answer is good but its not gonna help with my issue .

Comment: You mean , that no matter whatever entry you add but it sets back to default values.

Comment: Edited answer , since i just discovered that DNS resolving has gone some changes from Ubuntu 12.04 , which is why your settings get **OVERWRITTEN**.Also refer this question for info http://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf on that.

Answer (score 1):

First(optional), select a better mirror. Launch Synaptic Package Manager. Then click "Setting" → "Repositories". select the download source that's closest to you. [Drawback of this step: some local mirror is not updated.]

Then, install apt-fast with the following instruction:
http://www.webupd8.org/2010/08/you-can-now-install-apt-fast-from-ppa.html

Finally, create symbolic link by running:

> sudo mv /usr/bin/apt-get /usr/bin/apt-get_BACKUP

and then run

> sudo ln /usr/bin/apt-get_BACKUP /usr/bin/apt-get

If you encounter any problem, says apt-get no longer work, run this:

> sudo rm /usr/bin/apt-get

then this:

> sudo mv /usr/bin/apt-get_BACKUP /usr/bin/apt-get

Hope it helps.

EDIT: This issue seems irrelevant to DNS server. According to your photo, it shows a slow download speed/ unstable connection, instead of high domain name resolution delay.
Anyway, if you want to use another DNS server, consider OpenDNS.
Also, the maximum transfer rate of your modem is 236kbps, i.e. 29.5KB per second. Don't expect a fast Internet connection.

Comment: with a try of selecting best server from update manager's settings , its fine now .  so i want to know wht i cant edit my resolv.conf file . Thank you .

Comment: You may edit resolv.conf if you want. However, it is not necessary because it seems that it is irrelevant to the issue.DNS server is used to convert domain name to IP address. e.g. if you type www.google.com in the address bar, DNS will convert it into 74.125.71.104 .If you type 74.125.71.104 in address bar,instead of www.google.com, you can still browser the webste.Therefore, if your ISP's DNS server is not working properly,there would be a long delay before you can enter google's website by entering www.google.com in your addr bar. But it's not your case because you can access websites well.

Comment: see the post properly , i cant edit it and if i did so my changes will be overwritten , i already tried all to edit before i post it here .Thanks :)

Comment: You can't edit /etc/resolv.conf because the file is controlled by resolvconf. You have to configure the programs that use resolvconf to update resolv.conf. More generally, don't ask multiple questions in one AskUbuntu question, otherwise you are defeating the purpose of AskUbuntu. Your main original question was about `apt-get update` hanging. Your resolvconf question is completely different. And it has been asked before. And answered. And the answer is already in resolvconf(8).