# cant connect to internet directly on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, internet, proxy

I have dual booted machine windows 7 with ubuntu 12.04.
I dont have direct internet access in ubuntu on wired network although direct connection works in windows7.

I have to connect through a proxy on ubuntu, which works fine.
This is not a ubuntu version related problem as i have been getting it from ubuntu 11.04.

I want to know what difference is there in ubuntu and windows 7 which creates such results and how to fix it?

**EDIT**

In ubuntu i get the error on direct connection(google-chrome-stable) -

The server at www.example.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `resolv.conf` in Ubuntu was probably changed for proxy use and was not changed back for normal use for some reason. Deleting the old resolv.conf may help. You can make a backup copy of the file and delete the original with this single command:

```
sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/backup.resolv.conf
```

A new resolv.conf will be generated as and when needed.

Steps:

1. Boot into Ubuntu
2. disconnect from the Internet via proxy, if connected.
3. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter the command:

   sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/backup.resolv.conf
4. Connect to the Internet with the Direct connection settings.

To add a permanent dns entry to resolv.conf see: [How do I add a DNS server via resolv.conf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem to be resolv.conf was not getting updated bu network settings 
so i manually added google public dns and it works perfectly.

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.04 resolv.conf is dynamically generated. It may get over-written at some point. See how you can do it more permanently in the link in my answer. Please accept one of the answers (yours of mine) as the correct and put the green tick mark so that others can benefit from your question.