# can only connect to one network

Tags: wireless, internet, network-manager

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04 a couple of weeks ago on my HP laptop (completely replaced Windows). Everything seemed fine until a few days ago when I was unable to connect to the internet with my wireless network at home. I also tried three other wireless networks and also tried to connect by ethernet cable. These are all networks that I have been able to connect to in the past with no problems. In each case it says that I am connected to the network, but when I open Firefox I get the message "Firefox can't find server at start.ubuntu.com". I also tried Google Chrome and that didn't work either.

However, there is one network that I can connect to; the secure network at my school. The first time I noticed this problem was after I installed some updates at school and then went home and couldn't connect. I'm not sure if it had anything to do with these updates or if that's just a coincidence. When I came back to school it was fine and then it stopped working again went I went home.

Here's what I get for the following commands that phipsalabim suggested:

```
~$ lspci -v | grep -iA 7 network
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
Memory at d2500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

~$ iwconfig
 lo        no wireless extensions.

 wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"My School Secure"  
           Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: DC:7B:94:87:AE:E1   
           Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
           Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
           Power Management:off
           Link Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
           Tx excessive retries:3300  Invalid misc:570   Missed beacon:0

 eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Note that I'm at my school where I do have access.

```
~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no  

~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32474  1 
snd_hda_codec_idt      70795  1 
bnep                   18281  2 
rfcomm                 47604  0 
bluetooth             180153  10 bnep,rfcomm
parport_pc             32866  0 
ppdev                  17113  0 
binfmt_misc            17540  1 
snd_hda_intel          33773  5 
snd_hda_codec         127706  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              17764  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97275  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
i915                  477611  3 
drm_kms_helper         46978  1 i915
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
arc4                   12529  2 
drm                   241971  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
snd_seq                61929  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
uvcvideo               72627  0 
videodev               98259  1 uvcvideo
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
hp_wmi                 18092  0 
joydev                 17693  0 
sparse_keymap          13890  1 hp_wmi
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev
hp_accel               25976  0 
psmouse                97485  0 
wmi                    19256  1 hp_wmi
lis3lv02d              19876  1 hp_accel
i2c_algo_bit           13423  1 i915
video                  19651  1 i915
iwlwifi               401140  0 
mac_hid                13253  0 
wacom                  53300  0 
serio_raw              13211  0 
input_polldev          13896  1 lis3lv02d
lp                     17799  0 
mac80211              506862  1 iwlwifi
snd                    79041  19 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_ra    wmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
cfg80211              205774  2 iwlwifi,mac80211
soundcore              15091  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
hid_logitech_dj        18730  0 
ums_realtek            18248  0 
usbhid                 47238  1 hid_logitech_dj
hid                    99636  2 hid_logitech_dj,usbhid
r8169                  62154  0 
usb_storage            49198  1 ums_realtek
```

And for the wired connection.

```
~$ lspci -v | grep -iA 10 ethernet
   01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 3662
   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
   I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
   Memory at d0410000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
   Memory at d0400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
   Expansion ROM at d0420000 [disabled] [size=128K]
   Capabilities: <access denied>
   Kernel driver in use: r8169
   Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: Yes it sounds stupid, but turn your router off and on again. If nothing changes please open the terminal and run: `sudo service network-manager restart`. If that doesn't help please edit your question and post the output of the following commands: `lspci -v | grep -iA 7 network`, `iwconfig`, `rfkill list all`, `lsmod`. We should look at those anyway since you can't connect to other networks either.

Comment: my first guess is that it's an N speed problem

Comment: @phipsalabim  I did turn my router off when this first happened a few days ago. I'm not at home right now. Should I still try your other suggestions now? Once I go home I have no other way of getting on the internet.

Comment: forget network-manager restart. post the other ones.

Comment: edit your question, and post the output there. It's a little cumbersome in the comments, and difficult for others to see.

Comment: I added the output to my original post. I could try to connect to another network here at school that may give me the same error as I get at home and run those commands again if you think that would be helpful.

Comment: Are you using Juniper or another VPN at school? Is so It may be a DNS resolv.conf issue. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/156154/how-to-prevent-juniper-network-connect-breaking-dns-resolutions

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/189589/cant-connect-to-internet-directly-on-ubuntu

Comment: @ user68186 - Yes I am using Juniper. It was quite a hassle to get it to work. Someone configured that for me. I'm not exactly sure what they did, but they pretty much made a switch that would go between different versions of Java depending on whether or not the VPN was being used. I could try to find the file and post it.

Comment: Let me know if the answers to the two questions I referred to solves your problem. This is a known issue with Juniper. You have to type some commands (mentioned in the answers) in the terminal after logging off Juniper to get back to normal.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with with signing out of the VPN. The command `sudo service resolvconf restart` seems to do the trick. However, I only need to put that command in if I don't sign out of the VPN.

Comment: I found the same thing sometime ago. You may want to upvote this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/156154/how-to-prevent-juniper-network-connect-breaking-dns-resolutions/226282#226282

Answer (score 0):

Ok, everything looks fine. I am pretty sure this is a N-speed issue.

When you get home. Open the terminal and run:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
```

this turns off your wifi. Then run

```
sudo rmmod -f iwlwifi
```

this removes the module

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

this reloads the module with an additional option

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

this puts the wifi interface back up.

When you're done, connect to wifi and check if web pages are rendered

**These changes only apply to the current session.
If this fixes the issue you will have to make them permanent.**

In the terminal run:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

in the opened file (iwlwifi.conf) add this line

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

If that doesn't fix the issue, report back. I will bow my head in shame, and I'm sure someone more knowledgeable than me will figure out your problem.

good luck

---

Ethernet issue

12.04 is not compatible with your ethernet card. To fix this.

Download the driver [from this page](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=7&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) (scroll down to the linux/unix section and download the linux driver from the closest mirror) to your `~/Download` folder

then in the term run:

```
gksudo gedit  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

at the end of the file append:

```
blacklist r8169
```

save and close file, finally run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u && cd ~/Downloads && tar xvf r8101-1.023.00.tar.bz2 && cd r8101-1.023.00 && sudo sh autorun.sh
```

reboot

Comment: I couldn't find iwlwifi.conf in /etc/modprobe.d/. Is it supposed to be there? I also did a search for it and didn't find it.

Comment: you can just create an empty one. In the terminal run `sudo touch /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` then `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and add the line. Did this fix your issue?

Comment: I'm not home yet, so I haven't tried. I just wanted to look at the file out of curiosity.

Comment: The thing that worries me is that ethernet is not working either. Do you have ethernet access at school? Please post the output of `lspci -v | grep -iA 10 ethernet`.

Comment: OK, I did that.

Comment: edited answer for your ethernet connection. You should be golden after that.

Comment: That worked for the ethernet, but did not work for wireless. I am also using Juniper VPN if that would cause any problems.

Comment: *bowing my head in shame*. juniper is the most likely candidate. See the links user68186 posted in the comments to your question. Sorry