# The "resolv.conf" file becomes empty after each restart

Tags: network-manager, configuration, dns, resolv.conf

The "/etc/resolv.conf" file becomes empty after each restart and I lose the DNS data set in it. It only contains the following text each time:

> # Generated by NetworkManager

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That file has 2 comments in it:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

Why not listen to the people that made/maintain this file? ;-)

> resolveconf

From the man page:

> Normally the resolvconf program is run only by network  interface  con‐
>          figuration  programs  such  as  pppd(8)  (for  ppp interfaces); by DHCP
>          clients such as dhclient(8); by ifup(8) and ifdown; and by  DNS  caches
>          such as dnsmasq(8) (for the loopback interface).  These programs obtain
>          nameserver information from some source and push it to resolvconf.
>
> Command line
>
> The administrator can run resolvconf from the command line  to  add  or
>          delete  nameserver  information,  but this is not normally necessary or
>          advisable.

Please use the method described here: [How do I add a DNS server via resolv.conf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf) (Randall Cook seems the easiest and works for servers too).