# How do I change /etc/resolv.conf?

Tags: dns, resolv.conf

I am using ubuntu 12.04. How do I change `/etc/resolv.conf` file ?
Every time I edit it, it automatically gets reset. If I want to retain changes in the file what needs to be done. When I browsed through internet I found some solutions one of them was:

1. Adding the nameserver to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`
2. Adding the nameserver to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`

But even after adding the nameserver to above mentioned files and restarting the services, the `/etc/resolv.conf`  automatically gets reset.

I want to permanently retain changes in `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Comment: /questions/30942/why-does-my-resolv-conf-file-get-regenerated-every-time and http://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf `Every time I edit it, it automatically gets reset.` The remarks in the file tell you that it should not be edited and what you should do to add nameservers. See the link for 1 such method.