# apt-get not working on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: 12.04, server, apt, vps

I couldn't install any software using apt-get command in my VPS and the terminal prints:

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package python3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3' has no installation candidate
```

What's the problem?
I've tried apt-get update as root user and here is what is shown to me:

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get update
Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@ubuntu:~#
```

And my VPS place is in the Germany. Does it matter?

Comment: Did you run the command "sudo apt-get update" ??? does that work?

Comment: @Rat2000 Yes, I did and still doesn't work.

Comment: Possible Duplication of: [apt-get update fails to fetch files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)

Comment: Thank's but if I change my DNS server does it make any problem for my websites running on my VPS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fix your DNS resolver configuration, e.g the DNS server your own server is using to convert hostnames to IP addresses. This should not affect websites running on your VPS. Do not change DNS server your domains are using - that would break your websites.

You could either use your provider's DNS server (ask the settings from them, or check out their documentation), or for example [Google's public DNS resolvers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).

For instructions on how to change your DNS server, check out for example [this question on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried [CloaDNS](http://cloudns.net) and the server work fine.