# possible DNS problem unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: upgrade, dns, software-sources

I just upgraded my ubuntu server via command line to version 12.04.  I was on 11.10, so when I upgraded I have to switch the sources in `source.list` to the `old-releases.ubuntu.com` source.  Everything worked fine.

Anyway, now I want to upgrade again, but the problem is my server is having a problem contacted the `us.archive.ubuntu.com` server.  When I do `apt-get update`  I get many errors that look like this:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
```

Pinging `us.archive.ubuntu.com` doesn't work with `unknown host` error.  I also tried ping `google.com` and it didn't work either.  Pinging `8.8.8.8` however did work.  So I am wondering what has happened.  I was poking around the web and it seems like its a DNS issue, but I don't know what to do.  My `/etc/resolv.conf` file is blank.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

*I couldn't comment because of lacking REP*  Although this isn't directly an answer, my dedicated server is running 12.10 and my `resolv.conf` looks something like:

```
domain example.com
search exmaple.com
nameserver EXTERNAL IP 1
nameserver EXTERNAL IP 2
```

Where `example.com` is obviously my datacentres domain name, which I never removed or changed.  Although you could try [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf) or [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) for better help