# I messed up my /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf files, now my network doesn't work. How can I reset it?

Tags: networking, resolv.conf, hosts

I tweaked my system by installing ftp server and a dns server. I think in the process I messed up  resolv.conf and the hosts file.

Now I want to restore it but am not able to do so.
I am using ubuntu 14.04 x86_64.

Here is a screenshot that might help:

[image]

Comment: Could you post the instructions you followed and the current content of related config files hosts...?

Comment: i added 127.0.1.1 myname to the resolv.conf file.. everything was fine then i rebooted and everything gone.

Comment: Resolv.conf is generated file, sure you have seen this at top of it `#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN`. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf/130459#130459

Comment: You should include __in your question__ the version of Ubuntu you are using and whether it is a server version or a desktop (GUI) version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are running a currently-supported **desktop** version of Ubuntu, then networking should be handled by the `NetworkManager` service, and your `/etc/network/interfaces` file should contain only the default loopback interface definition

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

To fix your `/etc/resolv.conf` file, you probably need to reconfigure the package from the command line using

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

It will present you with a question about preparing /etc/resolv.conf for dynamic updates - answer "Yes". It may also present you with another question about temporarily appending your existing config to the dynamic one - if so you should probably answer "No" to that one. This will re-create the default symbolic link in place of your manually-edited file.

Comment: You are awesome..

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` with the correct settings.

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Then restart your network device:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

The `resolv.conf` will be recreated with the correct settings.

You can put the following in your hosts file if you want the defaults back:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 hostname

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

The second line is only needed if your pc has a name. (Don't forget to substitue the name).

Comment: in my case i have wlan1, as i am using network through this, but the command [sudo ifdown wlan1 && sudo ifup wlan1] do not work for me.... it is giving error as [ignoring unknown interface]

Comment: Can you post the output or a screenshot of the output from  sudo ifconfig and sudo ifdown wlan1