# DNS not working after upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq

I've recently upgraded my desktop from 12.04 to 14.04 and now my internet connection isn't working. I can access my router. I can go to Google by entering its IP address.

My resolv.conf file:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Per other instructions I've commented out `dns=dnsmasq` from /etc/NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=00:19:66:45:52:39,

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

If I don't have `dns=dnsmasq` commented out then my resolv.conf has this entry only:

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

At this point I am dumbfounded because from everything I know DNS should be working. I'm grateful for any help.

P.S. I should add that prior to the upgrade I had an FTP server running on the desktop for sending images from an office scanner. The scanner can't find the FTP server. Other office computers (including my laptop running 12.04) can use the internet fine.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I've got DNS working again. Since it appeared that DNS was being configured right I started wondering about iptables. I flushed the current iptables rules and DNS immediately began working. `iptables -F` However, the problem returns after rebooting. Now it appears to be a matter of making permanent edits to my iptables.

Apparently I had installed lokkit at some point in the past. I did a complete removal of lokkit and the problem was resolved over boot. I could tell that lokkit was involved because the output of `sudo iptables -L` included references to lokkit.

Comment: Remember, you can accept your own answer

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any particular reason to circumvent the use of dnsmasq? otherwise, I'd suggest reverting your changes to NetworkManager.conf and then [reconfiguring the resolvconf package](https://askubuntu.com/a/482276/178692).

After that, you should be able to add your chosen DNS servers via the 'IPv4 Settings' tab of the nm-applet GUI, after changing the mode from 'Automatic (DHCP)' to 'Automatic (DHCP) addresses only'.

Comment: The only reason I tried circumventing dnsmasq is because elsewhere I saw posts about a similar problem with users reporting that disabling dnsmasq by the method I followed fixed their problem. 

I've uncommented out dnsmasq in NetworkManager.conf and followed the instructions to reconfigure resolvconf. No success.

Answer (score 0):

Add your desired dns server to /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf on the line saying supersede domain-nameserver. Separate by comas your dns addresses. Save the file and restart the network manager

Comment: I'll try it when I get back into the office, but I've looked in the same file on my laptop and can't find a `supersede domain-nameserver` line. Do I need to create it?

Comment: I'll add copy of my own file once I get home to my ubuntu laptop =) or you can look into similar questions on my profile  - I posted before.  I think if you do `nl /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` , that will be line 18 or 20

Comment: I found in `/etc/dhcp/dhcliet.conf` the following line:
`#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;`
I changed it to:
`prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1, 10.1.10.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;`
I then restarted network-manager. The resolv.conf file changed from:
`nameserver 127.0.1.1`
to
`nameserver 10.1.10.1`
`nameserver 8.8.8.8`
`nameserver 8.8.4.4`
The problem persists. Note, the reason why I put 10.1.10.1 first is because that's the DNS for my laptop when it's connected wirelessly on the same network.

Comment: By the way, I can ping all of these DNS addresses without any problems. I really don't know what gives here. DNS appears properly configured in `/etc/resolv.conf` and my system can reach those addresses, but DNS doesn't work.

Comment: I've also tried changing `prepend` to `supersede`.  I've also tried using only one DNS address. Again, no resolution in either case.