# Lenovo G580 (Qualcomm Atheros AR8162) wired connection not working after some software update in 15.10

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, 15.10, atheros

Till Last month(17.11.2015) ethernet connection was working, then later a software update was happened thats all my wired connection stopped working.

But still I am able to connect wifi.

Output of `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:89:84:4a:6f:1e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3306 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3306 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:525800 (525.8 KB)  TX bytes:525800 (525.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:d0:5a:47:3a:aa  
          inet addr:131.159.210.110  Bcast:131.159.223.255  Mask:255.255.224.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2ed0:5aff:fe47:3aaa/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:593816 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:54033 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:73413459 (73.4 MB)  TX bytes:6613653 (6.6 MB)
```

Output of `lshw -C network`

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 20:89:84:4a:6f:1e
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:29 memory:e0500000-e053ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 2c:d0:5a:47:3a:aa
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.2.0-18-generic firmware=N/A ip=131.159.210.110 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:e0400000-e047ffff memory:e0480000-e048ffff
```

I tried the following

1. `sudo dhcpclient eth0`: terminal got hanged and I didn't get any response
2. I also tried editing the `gksu gedit /etc/network/interfaces` by adding lines for `eth0`. But after that my wired was not recognized at all, before that I was atleast able to see the ip address in connection information, therefore I removed those lines.
3. Tried downloading the `compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u.tar.bz2` but `make` throwed the following error

   ```
   error "ERROR: compat-drivers by default supports kernels >= 2.6.24, try enabling only one driver though"
   ```
4. Even replaced new cable, but no use.

Output of `uname -r`

```
4.2.0-18-generic
```

output of `lspci -nn | grep 0200`

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast
Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 10)
```

output of `dmesg | grep -e alx -e eth | tail -n10`

```
[   25.902102] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[11934.269510] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
[11934.270128] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
[25960.953248] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
[25960.954014] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
[39319.920165] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
[39319.921026] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready 
[39516.107284] alx 0000:01:00.0 eth0: NIC Up: 100 Mbps Full 
[39516.107736] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready 
[39516.235209] alx 0000:01:00.0 eth0: NIC Up: 100 Mbps Full
```

Output of `syslog`:

```
 cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i network | tail -n100
Nov 25 22:43:23 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Nov 25 22:43:23 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 90, deferring action for 4 seconds)
Nov 25 22:43:23 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Nov 25 22:43:24 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov 25 22:43:24 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Nov 25 22:43:24 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 100)
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed') [100 20 40]
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'carrier-changed') [40]
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none') [20 30 0]
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1'.
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) starting connection 'Wired connection 1'
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Nov 25 22:43:34 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Nov 25 22:43:35 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
Nov 25 22:43:35 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Nov 25 22:43:35 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Nov 25 22:43:36 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov 25 22:43:36 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Nov 25 22:43:36 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): disconnecting for new activation request.
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: activated -> disconnected (reason 'none') [100 30 0]
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) starting connection 'Wired connection 1'
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Nov 25 22:43:46 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Nov 25 22:43:47 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
Nov 25 22:43:47 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Nov 25 22:43:47 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Nov 25 22:43:47 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov 25 22:43:47 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Nov 25 22:43:47 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Nov 25 22:43:57 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Nov 25 22:46:04 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: activated -> disconnected (reason 'user-requested') [100 30 39]
Nov 25 22:46:04 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'user-requested') [39]
Nov 25 22:46:04 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Nov 25 22:46:04 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
Nov 25 22:46:04 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) starting connection 'Wired connection 1'
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Nov 25 22:46:13 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Nov 25 22:46:14 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
Nov 25 22:46:14 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Nov 25 22:46:14 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Nov 25 22:46:14 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov 25 22:46:14 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Nov 25 22:46:14 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Nov 25 22:46:24 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Nov 25 22:48:18 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 100, deferring action for 4 seconds)
Nov 25 22:48:18 vinod-Lenovo-G580 NetworkManager[763]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 100)
```

modinfo alx

```
vinod@vinod-Lenovo-G580:~$ modinfo alx
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-18-generic/updates/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Qualcomm Atheros(R) AR816x/AR817x PCI-E Ethernet Network Driver
author:         Qualcomm Corporation, <nic-devel@qualcomm.com>
author:         Johannes Berg <johannes@sipsolutions.net>
version:        backported from Linux (next-20151115-0-gf6cbb19) using backports backports-20151115-0-g732e101
srcversion:     B1915AE94C11FC9A0413975
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        compat,mdio
vermagic:       4.2.0-18-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

ipconfig/all in windows

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Vinod
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR8162/8166/8168 PCI-E F
ast Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 20-89-84-4A-6F-1E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::890b:7b3a:48ca:71cb%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.149.231.123(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::66d1:a3ff:fe17:4e11%12
                                       10.149.231.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 438339972
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-51-80-FF-20-89-84-4A-6F-1E

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1%12
                                       10.149.224.2
                                       10.156.33.53
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:4ed:15d:7509:fdf5(Prefer
red)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4ed:15d:7509:fdf5%3(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 134217728
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-51-80-FF-20-89-84-4A-6F-1E

   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{9A394F87-86A0-4D59-AD8D-6D1C4C147B81}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Network manager in Ubuntu:

[network manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwnhL.png)

Struggling for 2 weeks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? Please edit your question to add the result of: `dmesg | grep -e alx -e eth | tail -n10` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 : updated the output and one more thing I am using IPV4 connection

Comment: @chili555 please help me

Comment: So far, we see nothing wrong. Please look for further clues at: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i network | tail -n20` Please paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com By the way, the IPv6 lines in your log are insignificant and may be ignored; it simply means that no IPv6 address is available, perhaps because your ISP or router don't offer it.

Comment: @chili555 one more thing I am using dual OS

Comment: Any results from the data I requested above?

Comment: @chili555 now I am outside and using wifi...so is it ok to get the current output or do you want to execute when LAN is connected ?

Comment: With ethernet connected and wireless switched off, please.

Comment: @chili555 Since I am outside I need some time but I have checked the log and copied some info which might be useful for you to debug...I am updating in the question

Comment: Please try: 'sudo ethtool -s eth0  speed 100 autoneg off` Now will it stay connected? If so, I will propose a permanent solution.

Comment: @chili555 will update you in 8 hrs, since no internet I am forced to work outside

Comment: @VinodPrime Please use the correct formatting when posting. Using quoting instead of code makes everything highly unreadable :S

Comment: sorry this is my first question...next time i'll correct it

Comment: @chili555 Still it's not working. I have updated the syslog i.e after executing the sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 autoneg off

Comment: @chili555 What I should do next ?

Comment: I see a number of entries 'carrier off', 'carrier on', 'carrier changed', etc. Since the carrier comes from the router or switch, through the ethernet cable, is it possible this is a router or cable issue? Did you try an earlier kernel version? Did it help or no?

Comment: @chili555 yeah yeah I tried both changing cable and earlier kernel version but it doesn't help. Moreover it can't be a cable issue because I can connect to internet in windows

Comment: Is Wake-on-LAN enabled or disabled in the BIOS? Please try switching to the opposite. Reference: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=117717

Comment: @chili555 In BIOS i don't have any option like that..I can see only PXE boot to lan which was previously enabled...now i tried both but no effect.

Comment: Even i tried enabling the energy efficient of ethernet adapter in windows but still it didn'twork

Comment: @chili555 guess what yesterday I even reinstalled ubuntu but still wired internet not working. Still what other options left ?

Comment: @chili555 : is it something related to alx driver ?

Comment: @chili555 Where I can find the updated version for alx then ?

Comment: @chili555 I can update ethernet via wireless, but please let me know the command to update ethernet.

Comment: @chili555 Today I found one more thing in my workplace, automatic DHCP works for wired connection, only problem lies with Manual/static IP. Since I am living in student dorm, there only static IP is possible. I hope this might be good info for you

Comment: May I assume you have double-checked the address, netmask, gateway and DNS numbers? Where and how have you set the details? In Network Manager or where?

Comment: @chili555 Yes I set in network managers, but I use same details in windows and it works.

Comment: @chili555 I have updated the ipconfig/ all info from windows and network manager screenshot from ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 this looks to describe my problem, but i don't see any solution for this.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/553415/ubuntu-14-04-connection-is-there-but-no-internet-access-messed-resolvconf

Comment: What does yours report? `cat /etc/resolv.conf` I actually think this is your problem: `(eth0): carrier now OFF (device state 100, ` In other words, the carrier drops or at least the driver or card *thinks* it drops, and so it disconnects.

Comment: @chili555 yes you are right, this is my problem

Comment: But in next step my carrier is getting ON , then in theory my internet should work right, then why it's not working ?

Comment: @chili555 Any solutions ?

Comment: @chili555 I found one temp solution, the trick is whenever I connect wired connection in university with Automatic DHCP, then following that on the same day without shutting down my system, if I connect to my wired connection in home it works.

But if my shutdown my computer or close my laptop, then it is not working.

P.S. I tested this trick for 2 times and it works.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @chili555 Any fix for it ? am really struggling without internet.

Comment: I regret that I haven't any other suggestions. Sorry.

Comment: I also have a machine which contains this Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Ethernet device and I'm having exactly the same problem. However, I've found there is a bug reported, though still not fixed... https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70761 The bug was first reported 2014-02-18 and last discussed a few days ago on 2016-03-04. Some of the participants on that page above, refer to using an earlier kernel. Has anyone managed to do this, successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you update the ethernet driver `alx`. Download this package to your desktop: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/15/backports-20151115.tar.gz Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, back to the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
cd ~/Desktop/backports-20151115
make defconfig-alx
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement. We will probably have one more step.

Comment: it didn't work, I have updated modinfo alx output in the question

Comment: what's the next step ?