# Where is the content of my generated resolv.conf coming from?

Tags: resolvconf

I have a Ubuntu 14.10 server with `resolvconf` installed.

In `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`, I have:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

In `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`, I have:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

In `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original`, I have:

```
domain members.linode.com
search members.linode.com
nameserver 207.192.69.4
nameserver 207.192.69.5
nameserver 97.107.133.4
options rotate
```

My `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail` is symlinked to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original`.

Why is my `resolv.conf` generated like this?

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 74.207.242.5
nameserver 74.207.241.5
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search members.linode.com
domain members.linode.com
search members.linode.com
nameserver 207.192.69.4
nameserver 207.192.69.5
nameserver 97.107.133.4
options rotate
```

Where are the first 2 and fourth lines from? From my understanding, `resolvconf` should only use information from `head`, `base`, and `tail.

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Via DHCP perhaps? how/where is your interface configured?

Comment: From dhcp and networkmanager. See for instance: http://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf There is a 3rd one but I can't remember. Probably /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: Updated my question with the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`