# How do I change nameserver in Ubuntu?

Tags: dns

How can I change my `nameserver` but *WITHOUT* changing any file by hand, which command do I need to use for it?

```
root@ubuntu-1gb-nyc2-01:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
root@ubuntu-1gb-nyc2-01:~#
```

Comment: " generated by **resolvconf**" So do a `man resolvconf` and you have your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a DNS server via resolv.conf?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf)

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to always use the same nameserver (ie: you're not on a laptop or other mobile device) and want a permanent solution, you can try the following:

#### Set `/etc/resolve.conf` as Immutable

1. Edit `/etc/resolve.conf`
2. Set `/etc/resolve.conf` as immutable

   - `sudo chattr +i /etc/resolve.conf`

#### Remove `/etc/resolve.conf` Immutable

No program will be able to change the contents of your `/etc/resolve.conf` file, unless your remove the immutable flag:

1. `sudo chattr -i /etc/resolve.conf`

Comment: I'm not looking into making that change permanent, I just need to be able to run a command and specify nameserver. Is there a way to do so via command?