# Static DNS in Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, dns

I am a complete new-be when it comes to Linux and even more so when it concerns Ubuntu.

I want to configure the IPv4 settings to have automatic assigning of IP address but manual assigning for DNS. How do I do it?

Please teach me how to do it step by step.

Please take a look at the image to get an idea of what I am asking.

Thank you in advance.

Windows DNS settings example:

[image]

Comment: Am i assuming right that you added the windows screenshots only as reference, but you want to change the related data on a ubuntu machine?

Comment: You are absolutely right dufte.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using resolvconf

Open resolvconf config in gedit via

```
gksudo gedit /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original
```

This should result in a dialog asking for your password and then open the UI texteditor Gedit with the following file: `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original`

This file usually contains a line like that

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

This would mean there are to nameserver configured:
 - 8.8.8.8 and
 - 8.8.4.4

Edit the file to your needs and save & quit gedit.

Finish with

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

**UPDATE:**

Just realized [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf) covers the topic way better then i did.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information dufte but I do not have gedit installed. I can't install it too because the network will only work if i change the dns settings. please advise.

Comment: `gedit` was just an example. you can replace `gedit` with `nano` as well in the commands. But please follow the url i added to my post as it explains better what to do.