# Can't use DNS resolver even though I added to /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns, resolv.conf

I'm using a custom Ubuntu and I can't seem to use a DNS resolver. I updated my `/etc/resolv.conf` file so it would contain the line `nameserver 8.8.8.8`:

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

but that doesn't seem to help:

```
# ping google.com
ping: bad address 'google.com'
# ping google
ping: bad address 'google'
# ping www.google.com
ping: bad address 'www.google.com'
```

Accessing 8.8.8.8 as it is works:

```
# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=118 time=53.386 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=118 time=53.398 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=2 ttl=118 time=53.265 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=3 ttl=118 time=53.293 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=4 ttl=118 time=53.339 ms
```

I've tried looking for answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf) but most of the suggestions were irrelevant, as I don't have `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/`, `/etc/network/interfaces` or `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf`.

1. Could it be that I have another network configuration file that disables my `/etc/resolv.conf` (*The Linux I run had many programmers touching it along the years, and no one actually knows what exactly happens anymore...*)?
2. How actually `ping` is executed? *If I could understand when `ping` checks `/etc/resolv.conf`, maybe I could pinpoint why it isn't working*

---

This is my `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
#  cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
    passwd:     files  rf
    shadow:     files
    group:      files
    hosts:      files   dns
    services:   files
    networks:   files
    protocols:  files
    rpc:        files
    ethers:     files
    netmasks:   files
    netgroup:   files
    automount:  files
    aliases:    files
    bootparams:  [NOTFOUND=return] files
```

`ps auxc | grep -i dns` **OR** `ps auxc | grep -i resolv`

```
BusyBox v1.11.2 () multi-call binary

Usage: ps

Report process status

Options:
        w       Wide output
```

Comment: Does `ping 8.8.8.8` work ?

Comment: yeah, forgot to mention :-) Updated question

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, if present?

Comment: @MrShunz from looking at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html, my *nsswitch* seems to be configured right (at least the **hosts** part, which is the relevant part, if I understand correctly)

Comment: `nsswitch.conf` looks correct, can you do `nslookup google.com` and/or `dig google.com`?

Comment: well, not exactly. I was quite sure I work on Ubuntu, but one of the guys here said we work on an in-house ltib version, so it is not exactly Ubuntu (although `cat /etc/*{release,version}` does call the release-host "ubuntu-desktop"). In short I have no `dig / nslookup`.    Given this new info, I was under the impression that the existence of `/etc/resolv.conf` implies the functionality of a DNS resolver

Comment: Do you have a file `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`? If so, can you add its content to your question

Comment: Do **NOT** manually edit your /etc/resolv.conf file. Edit your question with the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `ps auxc | grep -i dns` and `ps auxc | grep -i resolv`. Let me know when you have it at @heynnema

Comment: @NickSillito No :-(

Comment: @heynnema BusyBox doesn't give anything useful :-(

Comment: Ah, you didn't say that you were at the BusyBox prompt. Type `fsck -f /`... if that doesn't work, type `exit`, then `fsck -f /`. Report back.

Answer (score 1):

I am noob but I faced this issue just few day ago! I think you should recreate your resolve.conf file.

Use this command for recreation.

`sudo resolvconf -u`.

May be this [helps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/accidentally-removed-resolvconf-package-how-to-get-it-back)!

Comment: This doesn't work on my machine [`-sh: resolvconf: command not found`], a sit is not exactly Ubuntu :-( I hoped it wasn't too far from Ubuntu, but I come to realize that it possibly is