# How to permamently add a nameserver to the /etc/resolv.conf?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, vpn, resolv.conf

I daily need to connect to a VPN from my Ubuntu Desktop 20.04, and each time I do that I need to edit the resolv.conf file, since it is constantly updated by NetworkManager. Its content is reset to:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

So I manually need to add a new line to be able to connect. Any idea how to make the new line to be permanent, or generated by the NetworkManager ?

TIA

Comment: What OS & release?   (are you using server? or desktop?  mention of NetworkManager implies desktop, but it's best if we're told)

Comment: Possibly useful - https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf

Comment: 1st line: `# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.`  so the answer is `man:systemd-resolved`

Comment: sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf