# Default search domain for /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: resolv.conf, systemd-resolved, resolvconf

With systemd-resolved, where does `DOMAINS` in search come from?

`/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

```
[Resolve]
DNS=1.1.1.1
Domains=lan
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search lan DOMAINS <----
```

`lan` is correctly populated, but there is an extra `DOMAINS` ?

Comment: Whats the question here?

Comment: Updated question for clarity

Answer (score 2):

The format for **/etc/resolv.conf**  (note there is no "d" in the filename) is documented in this [previously asked question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf)

You should not directly edit this file. Follow the instructions in the link above.

Comment: I am wondering where the `DOMAINS` in the generated file comes from. I am not editing /etcresolv.conf directly